# Python internal implementation

Tags: python

I am new to Python, I am coming from Java. I just want to see the python internal implementation like how I can see the java internal codes in eclipse by importing lib.

I was just trying to open `print()` method implementation in spider for python. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/

Comment: The python source code lives over here:  https://github.com/python.  It's not written in python.